# Python: Referring to different dictionary items in a dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary, design-patterns

I have a dictionary:

```
region = {
"DACH": ["Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria"],
"BLX":["Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg"]
}
```

I would like to add an item like this:

```
region = {
"DACH": ["Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria"],
"BLX": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg"],
"EUROPE": region["DACH"] + region["BLX"]
}
```

Python - rightfully so - complains about `Unresolved reference: region`.

I can solve this by using a lambda expression, like this:

```
region = {
"DACH": ["Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria"],
"BLX": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg"],
"EUROPE": lambda: region["DACH"] + region["BLX"]
}
```

Are there more elegant ways to do this in Python? It doesn't feel pythonic to me, but rather glued together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend simply doing this outside of the initial declaration. It's always tempting to try to one-line things in Python, because you usually can, but unless there's a very good reason to do this, the following is far easier to understand and maintain.

```py
region = {
    "DACH": ["Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria"],
    "BLX": ["Netherlands", "Belgium", "Luxembourg"],
}

region["EUROPE"] = region["DACH"] + region["BLX"]
```

If the number of keys goes beyond 3 or so, I'd also recommend using a list comprehension like so.

```py
region["EUROPE"] = [i for v in region.values() for i in v]
```